# When i press Backbutton doesn't work on phonegap(Android)?

Tags: javascript, cordova

At first time this code working fine ,but when i move to some other screen and came back to this screen back button not working.

```
   <script>
       function onLoad() {
           alert("device ready");
           document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
       }
   function onDeviceReady()
   {
       navigator.vibrate(0);
       document.addEventListener("backbutton",backKeyDown,false);

   }
   function backKeyDown()
   {
       document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);
       navigator.app.exitApp();
   }
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Fake Caller</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="onLoad()">
```

While app launch ->HomeScreen->backbuttonpress works.

Next Check ->HomeScreen->screen1->screen2->homescreen->backbuttonpress movesto screen2->backbuttonpress not works here.

What i want->homescreen->screen1->screen2->homescreen->exit.

What i did wrong please mention my fault and help me to over come this

Comment: What does the debugger says?

Comment: @JesperHøjer i didn't checked with that ,i just run using phonegap app

Comment: I would suggest that you download GapDebug, it will help you a lot with debugging your application.

Comment: @Vikram this is for android platform

Comment: @JesperHøjer ok sure i will try

Comment: @KishoreKumar you gotta note few things here. First, once you navigate to next page, ensure to remove backbutton listener. Then in backbutton listener button ensure to add preventdefault. The below code works for me in my app:

Comment: @KishoreKumar   function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);    
}

function onBackButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit ?", onConfirm, "Confirmation", "Yes,No");
}

function onConfirm(button) {
    if (button == 2) {
        return;
    } else {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
}

Comment: @KishoreKumar To remove listener use, document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);

Comment: @Gandhi bro on home screen when user press back button always i want to exit my app but above code works on first time when i moves to some screen its doesn't work y ?

Comment: @KishoreKumar It should exit from other screens as well?

Comment: @Gandhi bro i updated my question pls check it.

Comment: @KishoreKumar Ensure to add the code you posted inside body onload or document ready function so that it get initiailzed on load of homescreen everytime. Also its better to remove the listener once you move away fron home screen to subsequent screens

Comment: @Gandhi bro updated my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114941/discussion-between-gandhi-and-kishore-kumar).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found the Problem .

> I am used **window.open('');** so that each time new object was
>   created so the back button not works properly.
>
> ```
> Then i changed it to **window.location.href='';**
> ```

Then my back button problem solved .

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
Add in config.xml

```
<feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>
```